# utag for tealium is being coverted to file:// in ionic 3 after building into an Android app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, tealium

I have a utag_src with "https://......" (I have also tried "//tags.tiqcdn...." without the protocol) but after being called the first time, it sends 2 more times with http://

> http://tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/company/appname/environment/utag.3.js?event

This works fine on browser but after building it into an Android App, it's being converted to file:// and that's throwing me an error and I am no longer able to track things.

> file://tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/company/appname/environment/utag.3.js?event

Anyone know a way to either keep it in https or prevent it from converting into file:// in android?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with Ionic, but can certainly help steer you in the right direction with Tealium.

For mobile implementations it would be the recommendation to invoke Tealium via our SDKs: https://github.com/Tealium

With Ionic I believe you can use the Cordova SDK, or use the Native Android SDK, and write your own communication layer.

It will depend a little on what you want to achieve with Tealium, and with which product, but the SDKs are designed for mobile, so as well as solving your direct issue it will ensure optimal performance of Tealium event captures and triggers.  If you are solely looking for CDH support Tealium does have an HTTP API to receive events as well, but the SDK approach for all mobile requirements.

support@tealium.com can also help you to find the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use utag.js natively within Ionic.

In order to correctly get Tealium to work within your Ionic app, you should use the Tealium plugin for Ionic:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/tealium